# How to display title for Today's, Yesterday's and Day Before Yesterday's Post in separate Wordpress Loops

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show Wordpress Post's title based on date in three different Loops.

For Eg:

Today 5 posts, Yesterday 5 posts and Day Before Yesterday 5 posts.

From the above example, i need 3 loops.

1. Today's Post Alone.
2. Yesterday's Post Alone.
3. Day Before Yesterday's Post Alone.

Could any one please give me the code for my thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $today = getdate();
    $yday =  getdate( $today[0] -86400 );
    $yyday = getdate( $yday[0] - 86400);

    $todays_loop = new Wp_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'date_query' => array(
                'year' => $today['year'],
                'month' => $todaye['mon'],
                'day' => $today['mday']
            )
        )
    );

    $ydays_loop = new Wp_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'date_query' => array(
                'year' => $yday['year'],
                'month' => $yday['mon'],
                'day' => $yday['mday']
            )
        )
    );
    $yydays_loop = new Wp_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'date_query' => array(
                'year' => $yyday['year'],
                'month' => $yyday['mon'],
                'day' => $yyday['mday']
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

As you see here I picked three date information with the help of php getdate function. And then used the WP date_query to fetch the posts